# TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined in promise?

Tags: javascript

Why I can not get property `userId` inside class?

```
   connection
          .start()
          .then(function() {
            connection
              .invoke("join", this.userId)
              .then(function() {
                this.pushPassportData();
              })
              .catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
            return console.error(err.toString());
          });
```

In this line:

```
 .invoke("join", this.userId)
```

`userId` is declared as private property class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` inside your anonymous function refers to `window`, you can use arrow functions instead to solve this problem:

Try the following:

```
connection
          .start()
          .then(()=> {
            connection
              .invoke("join", this.userId)
              .then(()=> {
                this.pushPassportData();
              })
              .catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));
          })
          .catch(err=> {
            return console.error(err.toString());
          });
```